# How do I resist image upload again on edit if it's not required?

Tags: symfony

So I have the fields name, dob, and image. When I want to update data name and dob fields are filled with data but not image. I want to edit data say the name I have to upload the image again. If I do not wish to re-upload image again how do I stop it?

I tried with 'required' attribute but didn't work?

Comment: If it's not required you shouldn't need to re-upload the image - could you add you model, controller and form classes to the question?

Comment: basically I want image name to load in Input on edit..

Comment: In that case I suggest adding your view (template) file along with the ones requested above :-)

Comment: Can you show How to do it?